# Angular 6,7 How to apply default theme color to mat-sidenav background?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am hoping to have the background of a `mat-sidenav` the same as my `mat-toolbar` - theme color.

In `src\styles.scss` I have:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

My template / HTML file has:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    Title text
</mat-toolbar>
```

That shows nicely as indigo menu bar with the `menu` icon and `Title text`.
Below I want a `mat-sidenav` (that will have menu items) and I expect the entire background of the `mat-sidenav` area have the same color as the:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
```

which is indigo - defined by the theme.

The HTML code continues for rendering `mat-sidenav`:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened>
        <app-vertical-menu></app-vertical-menu>  // renders the menu items
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div class="app-main-area">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The `mat-sidenav` background and colors are untouched by the applied theme and its background colors are blank.

I know I can style the `mat-sidenav` background within the component using class name in the template - e.g:

```
...
<mat-sidenav #sidenav2 mode="side" opened class="vertical-menu">
...
```

and in the style/scss file:

```
.vertical-menu {
    background-color: navy !important;
}
```

But instead I want to apply the theme color of the default theme (e.g: `indigo-pink.css`), so the `mat-sidenav` background color is the same as the theme that we use to get our toolbar color

Answer (score 20):

You would need to apply a ***custom theme*** to your component. To summarize:

1. **Define your theme** in `style.scss`
2. **Define component theme**, ex. `my-component.component.scss-theme.scss`. This can be different from `my-component.component.scss`. You can separate out theming (color and typography) in theme file and other things (sizing, position, etc.) in the non-theme file.
3. **Include and call component theme** in `style.scss`

I have created a sample application on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdbvpa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav%2Fsidenav.component.html). As you would see, `mat-sidenav` and `mat-toolbar` are having the same theme. You can try by giving `color=primary|accent|warn` to `mat-toolbar` and `mat-sidenav`

[Tomas Trajan](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan) has written a very nice medium blog at [The complete guide to Angular Material Themes](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-complete-guide-to-angular-material-themes-4d165a9d24d1). You can find Angular team's document at [Theming your own components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components).

**Update 12th Dec 2019**

I have created a series of posts for detailed understanding of Angular Material Theme on Medium. You can find them here: [Create](https://medium.com/cmind/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-create-a-theme-42229068271d), [Understand](https://medium.com/cmind/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-understand-theme-1cb7f9e6efc5) and [Apply](https://medium.com/cmind/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-apply-theme-c12ce3bfa4a) theme.

**Update 1st October 2020**

I have created updated series of posts for detailed understanding of Angular Material Theme on Medium. You can find them here: [Create](https://indepth.dev/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-part-1-create-a-theme/), [Understand](https://indepth.dev/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-part-2-understand-theme/) and [Apply](https://indepth.dev/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-part-3-apply-theme/) theme.

Comment: But these are for custom components, I'm trying to modify a already created component, the sidenav surface.

Comment: @Germán could you please elaborate more?

Comment: These guides above work for custom components. But I'm using the component that angular material offers. So this is not working for such case.

Comment: In the example, sidenav is a component in folder, with ts, html and so. I'm using provided side nav with material components, implicit, not created as a component.

Comment: @Germán I think you didn't check the html of side nav component, it's using material side nav only.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you want(me neither), but I defined a class in my *styles.css* with the same primary color as indigo-pink theme

`.background-primary { background-color: #3f51b5; }`

and my mat-sidenav like this:

`<mat-sidenav class="background-primary"...`